# Has the choice of "network mode" an effect on battery when mobile data is switched off?

Tags: battery, mobile-data, 3g, 4g, 2g

I have read that 2G uses less battery than 4G LTE, especially if I don't need much data.

Some sources :

https://www.uswitch.com/mobiles/guides/how-can-i-make-my-phone-battery-last-longer/

[Does 4G consume more battery than 3G if I don't use it for data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160490/does-4g-consume-more-battery-than-3g-if-i-dont-use-it-for-data)

https://www.telecomhall.net/t/why-lte-4g-drains-battery-faster-than-2g-3g/138

Now, my question is : if I switch mobile data off, has the "mobile network" setting (2G/3G/4G) still an impact on battery consumption ?

The reason behind this question is that I am looking for the most battery-efficient configuration in my use case. Most of the time I am connected through Wi-Fi. Mobile data is switched off. Now, as for the mobile network setting, is there some kind of optimization to be done ? I'm hesitating between 2 settings :

- The default setting is 4G with VoLTE on
- Or would it be more battery efficient to switch VoLTE off, and activate 2G ?

Comment: Where did you read that? And when was that information posted? When a technology is new it usually draws more power, e.g. first 5G phones had a very high power consumption when 5G was active. Now the 5G models don't need much more power. So it may be that 4G was using more power when it was new but now I don't think it really matters. Also before VoLTE was present in all devices the phone had to keep a 3G or 2G connection additionally to the 4G connection for phone calls.

Comment: Where did I read that ? Well, there's a bunch of websites pretending that, some very recent (2021). I just updated my post with my sources. I also added some infos as for why I ask that question